# Make a bootable usb in a ubnutu 16.04 chroot (from chromeos)

Tags: unity, chromebook, startup-disk-creator

i cant find the startup disk creator on 16.04 chroot. anyone help?
create a chroot on your Chromebook:  https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton

Comment: You want to use your installed "crouton" to create an Ubuntu bootable disk, so that you can install Ubuntu on another system?

Comment: 16.04 goes EOL in just a few months.

Comment: @jad yes i want to install on my desktop

Comment: @David ok thanks for your info, just a doubt, will it go eol in ubnutu or will it get eol in crouton also?

Comment: @ShreyasBollapragada it looks like you can get a newer version of Ubuntu using `crouton` https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton#hey-now-ubuntu-1604-is-pretty-old-im-young-and-hip probably worthwhile upgrading ... if you're looking to install Ubuntu on a non-Chromebook then you don't need to do this inside `crouton`, you can do this straight from the ChromeOS. If you're looking to install `crouton` on another device, you will need to install it manually on the ChromeOS, not from a bootable device.